# Why isn't viewbag values displaying in browser even it return values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]List of items passing from an action method  to another action in my controller and the values stored into the View Bag. Even it shows values while debugging. It isn't displaying on the browser. I want to put these values in a select box. How could i solve this? somebody please help me.

** in Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.s = TempData["plist"];
    return View("Index"); 
}


[HttpPost]
     public ActionResult  matchpin(string id)
        {
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            List<pin> plist = new List<pin>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getpin", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", d);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var pin = new pin()
                        {


                            po = Convert.ToString(reader["po"]),

                        };
                        plist.Add(pin);
                    }


                }
            }

            TempData["plist"] = plist;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");

        }
```

**In view:

```
<select name="postoffice">                   
    <option>-select-</option>
    @if (ViewBag.s != null)
    {
        foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)
        {
            <option value="@f.po">@f.po</option>
        }
    } 
</select>
```

Comment: Are able to debug `foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)` line of code?

Comment: yes sir.And it shows values too.But when it comes to browser it is not showing

Comment: Don't put `<option>-select-</option>` in a loop otherwise it will add select many times in you select dropdown

Comment: yup.I corrected.But still the values are not displaying in browser.am after this fr the last week.Please help me

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `@if` statement on mvc *.cshtml file and share your screenshot having values, so we could figure out what's the problem

Comment: added the picture.In browser the option field is not showing values

Comment: Now check your web browser source code, is it contains that values ?

Comment: You can do it following way :

foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)
{
   <option value="f.po">f.Name<option>
}

Comment: Check and follow same syntax like my example and let me know

Comment: You dont need to use @ if you already used with @If condition

Comment: no sir.It isn't Working.without @ its not reading inside

Comment: and also i have tried inspect element option in the browser and it shows nothing in the option box

Answer (score 1):

You can view the data in select list like that

**In Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string firstnamevalue = "Hello";
        string lastnamevalue = "Welcome";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add(firstnamevalue);
        list.Add(lastnamevalue);

        TempData["plist"] = list;
        ViewBag.s = TempData["plist"];
        return View("Index");
    }
```

**In View**

```
<select name="postoffice">
<option>-select-</option>
@if (ViewBag.s != null)
{
    foreach (var f in ViewBag.s)
    {

        <option value="@f">@f</option>
    }
}
```

**Output**
[image]
When you can not satisfy this answer, please edit your question in the controller.
Then tell me how do you pass data?

Comment: @Ajay please provide more details in Index controller how type you store(pass) data in TempData["plist"].

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy if you cast the viewbag object back to the list. This will also give you back insistence.

```
<select name="postoffice">                   
    <option>-select-</option>
    @if (ViewBag.s != null)
    {
        foreach (var f in (List<pin>) ViewBag.s) // See casting back here <---------
        {
            <option value="@f.po">@f.po</option>
        }
    } 
</select>
```